# Redirect back to the post after login in the WordPress custom login page

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.8.2, I have a custom login page `http://www.....com/login`.

Site allows only logged in users to post comments and below redirect URL link is published on the comments section for user to login:

```
http://www......com/login/?redirect_to=http://www......com/post-name
```

I am trying to redirect back to the post after login with below function:

```
function redirect_to_posts_after_login($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to) {
    $redirect_to_post = $_GET['redirect_to'];
    if (!$redirect_to_post === "") {
        return $redirect_to_post;
    } else {
        return $requested_redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_posts_after_login', 10, 3);
```

However, it still redirects to `wp-admin` after the login. How can I make the redirect back to the post?

Comment: Try to set a higher priority for the filter: add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_posts_after_login', 5, 3);

Comment: Did not worked, tried setting `5,1` as well with no luck.

Comment: Your function should throw an error since you specify 3 parameters yet you only call 2

Comment: Surprisingly, no.

Comment: although your solution seems correct, you can still use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for testing a new approach to see if the problem is about getting a redirect URL or is from somewhere else.

Comment: @Ruvee yes, slash is there my code.

Comment: @behzadmsalehi tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as well, but no luck.

Comment: @Ruvee I am using a custom code. Checked and disabled all other login redirection functions as well, but found no conflict.

Comment: did you trace your code ? did redirect_to_posts_after_login function execute ? did you try to add action instead of filter ? what value  $_GET['redirect_to'] gets while  execution?

Comment: I tested with `var_dump($_GET['redirect_to']); die;`  right after function start with both `add_filter` and `add_action`. Still it just redirected to `wp-admin`. I have tried `wp_create_user()` as well, but no luck. Is there any other better ways to test?

Comment: Seems like there's a typo in the if condition. Should be `if ($redirect_to_post !== "")` as the `!` turns the equality left part a boolean

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['redirect_to']);`die;` returns `null` on `wp_login.php` page. `var_dump($_POST['user_login']);` also returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

With below changes, now I am able to return the user to the post after login.

Login URL at each post remained same as below with `redirect_to`:

```
http://www......com/login/?redirect_to=http://www......com/post-name
```

In  my custom login page template `login` I am capturing the `redirect_to` value as a variable:

```
$redirect_back_to = $_GET['redirect_to'];
```

And then in the same custom login page I have this hidden input field that take the `redirect_to` as input value:

```
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $redirect_back_to; ?>" name="redirect_to_post_url">
```

In the below function I am capturing the post referrer URL from the above input and checks if there is a referrer (`redirect_to`) it will redirect to the post else to `wp-admin`:

```
function redirect_to_posts_after_login($redirect_to) {
    $redirect_to_post = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'redirect_to_post_url');

    if (!$redirect_to_post === "") {
        wp_redirect(esc_url($redirect_to_post));
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_posts_after_login', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Note that the expression `!$redirect_to_post === ""` is evaluated as `(!$redirect_to_post) === ""`, i.e. `boolean === string`, which always returns `false`. And instead of the (bad) `wp_redirect()` call, how about changing the `if` to `return $redirect_to_post ? $redirect_to_post : $redirect_to;` ?

Answer (score 1):

`!$redirect_to_post === ""` will always return false !

can you try with this code?

```
function redirect_to_posts_after_login($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to) {
    $redirect_to_post = $_GET['redirect_to'];
    if ($redirect_to_post !== "") {
        return $redirect_to_post;
    } else {
        return $requested_redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_posts_after_login', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to redirect the user, to your desired custom URL after login. Then you should insert your custom URL here:-

```
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            //check for admins
            if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
                // redirect them to the default place
                return $redirect_to;
            } else {
                //you shud concatinate your custom url here
                return home_url();
            }
        } else {
            return $redirect_to;
        }
```

$redirect_to variable contains the URL to the wp-admin. But as a user apart from admin. You can insert the custom URL beside the home_url() function.(Concatinate your custom url in the form hard coded string)

Comment: I have to redirect to the referrer page (a post), since I have a custom login page `/login`, which itself is a redirect page of `wp-login.php` the referrer is always `/login` page in the function, not the actual post referrer URL.

Comment: As far as I know, a referral is a key that contains the saved address of the post? In simple terms it contains a URL, right? If 'yes', the simply get that url, and insert it in return home_url(), after deleting the home_url() function keyword. The process i gave is correct. Just simply insert the url string

Comment: You can use this to redirect to a specific post as well.


  global $post;
  $post_slug = $post->post_name;
 if($post_slug == 'my-account') { //can add multiple conditions
//create dynamic redirect page link
$redirect = urlencode(site_url().'/'.$post_slug);
//redirection
 wp_safe_redirect(site_url().'/wp-login.php/?redirect_to=' .$redirect);
 exit;
 }

Comment: The referrer page is user dynamic as this login link is placed at every post, I want the user to come back to the same post after the login. This input field `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>" name="redirect_to">`  and the `redirect_to` parameter in the login link contains the post URL. Since `wp-login.php` is redirected to `/login` the referrer is always `/login` page at `wp-login.php` and redirects to `wp-admin`.

Comment: unfortunately the wp_get_referrer gives this value SITE_URL/wp-login.php?loggedout=true&wp_lang=en_US. This is why you need to set your last post id URL in a session and redirect the user after he or she logs in. Or you need to enter the custom site URL